# Generating the same result as JavaScript's Date object but in Java

Tags: java, date

I want an easy way to generate exactly the same result as the JavaScript Date function but in Java.

**Javascript:**

```
> new Date()
Sat Jul 02 2022 22:49:06 GMT-0800 (Alaska Daylight Time)
```

**Java:**

```
> System.out.println(new Date());
Sat Jul 02 22:49:06 AKDT 2022
```

**Want:**

```
> System.out.println(new Date());
Sat Jul 02 2022 22:49:06 GMT-0800 (Alaska Daylight Time)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the latest Java 8 date API with a custom timestamp format string:

```java
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss OOOO (zzzz)");
System.out.println(dtf.format(zdt));
```

On the demo tool where I tried this (which server happens to be in Europe), I got this output:

```
Sun Jul 3 2022 09:14:27 GMT+02:00 (Central European Summer Time)
```